# How can I wrap a ggplot column n times after hitting threshold number

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have a barplot where I have one entry that is so much larger then my other entries that it makes it difficult to do interesting analysis on the other smaller valued data-points.

```
plt <- ggplot(dffd[dffd$Month==i & dffd$UniqueCarrier!="AA",],aes(x=UniqueCarrier,y=1,fill=DepDelay))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(breaks=late_breaks,labels=late_breaks,limits=c(0,150),colours=c('black','yellow','orange','red','darkred'))
```

[image]

When I remove it I get back to an interesting degree of interpretation but now I'm tossing out upwards of half the data and arguably the most important one to explore.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way that I could set an interval on my bar plot, say 500 in this case, after which I can start another column for the same entry right under it and resume building up my bar plot. In this example, that would translate here into WN splitting into 3 bars of length 500 500 and ~400 stacked one below the other all under that one WN label (ideally it shows the one tick for all three). Since I have a couple of other disproportionately large representative, plots doing this in as a layer during the plotting is of great interest to me.

Comment: Can you share the data by `dput(dffd)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah the file itself is quite large, so here is a dput with 1000 random sample rows https://pastebin.com/uQrCCCmA

Comment: Originally I loop over each month to populate this data (==i) so if you replace i with a specific integer between 1 and 12 you can just print a particular month.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you have such disproportionate values in your data set, you should either put your values on a `log` scale (or use some other transformation) or zoom in on the plot using `coord_cartesian`. I think you probably could hack your way around and create the desired plot, but it's going to be quite misleading in terms of visualisation and analysis.

EDIT:

Based on your comments, I have a rather hacky solution. The data you've pasted was not directly usable (a part of `dput` was missing + there's no `DepDelay` columns, so I improvised).

The idea is to create an extra tag column based on the `UniqueCarrier` column and the `max` amount you want.

```
df2 <- df %>%
    filter(UniqueCarrier != "AA" & Month == i) %>%
    group_by(UniqueCarrier) %>% 
    mutate(tag = paste(UniqueCarrier, rep(seq(1, n()%/%500+1), each=500), sep="_")[1:n()])
```

This adds a `tag` column that basically says how many columns you'll have in each category.

```
plt <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=tag, y=1, fill=DepDelay)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_gradientn(breaks=late_breaks, labels=late_breaks,
                         limits=c(0,150),
    colours=c('black','yellow','orange','red','darkred')) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=str_replace(sort(unique(df2$tag)), "_[:digit:]", ""))
plt
```

[image: example]

In the image above, I've used `CarrierDelay` with break interval of 100. You can see that the `WN` label then repeats - there are ways to remove the extra ones (some more creative replacements in `scale_x_discrete` labels.
If you want the columns to be ordered differently, just replace `seq(1, n()%/%500+1)` with `seq(n()%/%500+1, 1)`.

[image: example2]

Comment: my first intuition was to use a log plot as well, however with a bar plot I couldnt get the demarcation of each item in the plot, and with a column plot like this where I've assigned a value of 1 to each item to mimic a count when I try to apply scale_y_log10() it applies the logarithmic transformation to each y=1 value instead of the final count (and this makes the y value 0 and all the bars become 0 in length)

Comment: I see what you mean - in that case, `coord_cartesian` seems like a better option where you can first show the full graph and then the zoomed in graph.

Comment: that being said, there are cases where this type of plot is useful since it's a way of being area preserving, so if you have any idea of how to go about it that might be helpful. An example would be like around the 4:30 mark at this video https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/1/1b/Wealth_Inequality_in_America_by_politizane.webm/Wealth_Inequality_in_America_by_politizane.webm.360p.vp9.webm